# What would be an alternative for parameters?

Tags: winapi, portable-executable

We may all have used (sooner or later) Parameters to define how our Application should start or to add more infos to it. Either you can use `lpParameters/lpCommandLine` in `ShellExecute(ex)/CreateProcess` or even use it in a direct call in the cmd like this `MyApplication.exe -parameter1 -parameter2 -n`.

Sometimes there are conflicts with applications that use the same parameter names for different purposes or nowadays you can even see which parameters have been used for an Application. I was wondering if it is possible to use a different method on how to add more infos to my application BEFORE it actually starts (like parameters). I don't know much about the PE System (yet), but I was wondering if it was possible to use the `CreateProcess` API and start the Application suspended - write/change/modify (with `WriteProcessMemory`) an offset of a constant (or var) that I have declared in my sourcecode (or something like that...) and finally resume it.

I'm sure it is possible but It comes with some questions like:

1. How/Where can I get the offset of a constant from a PE file?
2. What happens if the file is packed/crypted?
3. Many more

So the final question would be - What would be an alternative for parameters? (maybe based on my idea?!)

Comment: Since the application decides how input is passed to it there is no alternative to following the rules mandated by a particular application. If an application mandates to be passed parameters on the command line then you will have to pass parameters on the command line. With the obvious out of the way, what is your real question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other ways to pass data to a new process when it starts running without resorting to hacking its memory beforehand.

[How do I pass a lot of data to a process when it starts up?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/11/56043.aspx)

[Undocumented and hard-to-find information regarding the CreateProcess API call](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/undocumented-createprocess) (scroll down to the **"Pass arbitrary data to a child process!"** section)

Comment: This is unbelievable! The undocumented `StartupInfo` "hack" does the job. Even better than my the idea I've had. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: The second method - while an interesting read - is a pretty dirty hack as well. The page even notes: *"Apparently this method does not work under 64bit Windows Vista."*